# MongoDB: Combining compound shard key with different compound indexes

Tags: mongodb, indexing, sharding

Let's say I have a collection with a shard key of {a:1, b:1}.

Alongside the index for the shard key, I also have an index of {a:1, **c**:1, **d**:1} - note the shard key doesn't prefix this index.

If I run a query only specifying values for the fields a, c, and d, can Mongo run a combination of both indexes to query only the correct shard and query the data using the second index? Or is this not possible (perhaps because just providing 'a' is not sufficient to choose the correct shard)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in the manual for [shard key indexes](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/sharding-shard-key-indexes/), the index can be an index on the shard key or a compound index where the shard key is a prefix of the index.

That means you would have to have an index of `{a:1, b:1}` or a compound thereof, *before* using it as the shard key.

Now let's say you have two indexes of `{a:1, c:1, d:1}` and `{a:1, b:1}`. You can run [.explain()](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.explain/) on a query to find out which index would be utilised by the query. See also [Explain Results](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/explain-results/).

Lastly, just because a query can not utilise the shard key does not mean it is not possible to be executed. It only means that `mongos` will need to query all shards, thus slightly sub-optimal. When you use the shard key in your query, it is able to 'jump' directly to the correct chunk on the correct shard.

You may find [Sharded Cluster Query Router](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/sharded-cluster-query-router/) a useful read.